# Set the value of a cell based on the combination of 2 separate cells

Tags: excel

I have Column B listing different operating system, Columns C shows how many days B has been offline. I would like D to show "Attention" if there is a Windows Server that the value of C is greater than 0.

I have tried a few combinations of formulas however none seem to give me the results I am looking for.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,"Windows Serv*",C:C,">0"),"Attention","")
```

The formula I tried just fills all of Column D with "Attention" regardless of the operating system or the days offline being show which is not what I want.

Comment: Can you add some sample data? Not sure if you want `COUNTIFS` on the entire column - it sounds like you are comparing row by row?

Comment: Let say that B2 = Windows Server 2012 and C2=1 I would like D to = Attention, Also in an attempt to not have to specify each operating system in a formulas I was hoping the "Windows Serv*" would work for me.

Comment: `=IF(AND(LEFT(B2,14)="Windows Server",C2>0),"Attention","")`

Comment: This one works!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Windows Serv",B:B)),C:C>0),"Attention","")
```